# DD Zero Error: No space left on device

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, dd

Hi currently I am getting a problem with this script when running it on one of our xenial servers to mass wipe a batch of drives in one command.
Firstly all the drives show up in lsblk, so that is not a problem and they will wipe individually if I initiate `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<insert drive path> bs=64KB status=progress` in multiple tabs, however recently I am having the problem of this error:

```
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb'$'\n''sdc'$'\n''sdd': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000280477 s, 0.0kB/s
```

Any idea what is causing this problem? I have left my code below. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
erasure=
RAIDFILE="/tmp/raiddrives"
sudo rm "$RAIDFILE"
echo "Drive Wiper 1.3"
echo "Waiting for Disks to initilise"
sleep 30s # Waiting for the HDDs and SSDs to power up.

sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 set alarm=off
sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 show | grep -E ^[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]] >> $RAIDFILE
while read LINE; do
    declare -a slotinfo
    IFS=' ' read -r -a slotinfo <<< "$LINE"

    if [ "${slotinfo[2]}" == "UBad" ] && [ "${slotinfo[3]}" == "-" ]; then
    IFS=':' read -r -a driveid <<< "${slotinfo[0]}"
    sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/e"${driveid[0]}"/s"${driveid[1]}" set good
    echo "${slotinfo[0]} has been set to good "

    if [ "${slotinfo[2]}" == "UGood" ] && [ "${slotinfo[3]}" == "F" ]; then
      sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/fall delete
      echo "Deleted foreign RAID config on ${slotinfo[0]} "
    fi

    if [ "${slotinfo[2]}" == "UGood" ]; then
    sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 add vd r0 drives="${slotinfo[0]}"
    echo "${slotinfo[0]} available for erasure"
    fi
done < "$RAIDFILE"

echo 'Available drive(s) to be wiped' #print a list of the unmounted drives only
declare -a drivevar
drivevar=$(lsblk | awk {'print $1'} | grep '^sd' | grep -v 'sda\|sdb') #removed nvme in live version
echo $drivevar
read -p "Confirm erasure of drives, or to amend list (Y/N/A): " erasure #confirm disk erasure
erasure=${erasure^^} #capitalise erasure

yesnocheck=0 #checking if the user enters a yes or no command.
while [[ yesnocheck -eq 0 ]]; do
  case "$erasure" in
    Y|YES)
      yesnocheck=1
      : handle 'yes' cases #dont need any special actions to happen for yes or no cases
      ;;
    N|NO)
      yesnocheck=1
      : handle 'no' cases
      ;;
    A|AMEND)
      unset drivevar 1>&2 #will loop error, and constantly ask for a yes no answer until it receives one.
      declare -a drivevar
      read -p "Confirm which drives to erase e.g.sda (each seperated by a space)" drivevar
      read -p "Confirm erasure of drives, or to amend list (Y/N/A): " erasure
      erasure=${erasure^^}
      ;;
    *)
      printf '%s\n' "Not a valid selection" 1>&2 #will loop error, and constantly ask for a yes no answer until it receives one.
      read -p "Confirm erasure of drives, or to amend list (Y/N/A): " erasure
      erasure=${erasure^^}
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ "$erasure" = "Y" -o "$erasure" = "YES" ] ; #or inside a statement
then
{ for i in "${drivevar[@]}"; #getting the results from the drivevar array
do
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/"$i" bs=64KB status=progress & #Parrallell Wiping process, wait allows the process to be cancelled although the process is slower.
  done
  wait
      }
elif [ "$erasure" = "N" -o "$erasure" = "NO" ] ;
then
  printf '%s\n' 'Operation Aborted!'
else
  echo "Ooooops!" #something has gone wrong somewhere, this shouldnt show.
fi
```

Comment: You are not splitting `${drivevar[@]}`, `IFS` is not set to `\n` when parsing that.

Comment: ah ok I'll give that a try, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You declared `drivevar` as an array but you are using it as a single-element string.

For example, `drivevar=$(lsblk...)` assigns the output to the first (zeroth) element  of the array, and `echo $drivevar` outputs this same element. But you're not using it as an array; you're using it just as a string containing a list of whitespace-separated items.

This means that when you try to iterate over it with `for i in "${drivevar[@]}"`, all the results are in the first (and only) element.

You should probably be using array assignments of the form `var=(element element…)`,

```
drivevar=( $(lsblk …) )               # Assignment
echo "drivevar=( ${drivevar[@]} )"    # Debug line, I assume
```

Oh. You'll want to delete the file you created that caused the original error. Beware that the filename contains newlines, so it may look strange when you use `ls` or `rm`. Use `rm -i` to require confirmation before deletion:

```
rm -i /dev/sdb*sdc*sdd*
```

---

As an aside, your assignment expression can be simplified from this

```
lsblk | awk {'print $1'} | grep '^sd' | grep -v 'sda\|sdb'
```

to something like this, which avoids the `awk | grep` antipattern

```
lsblk -dn -o NAME | awk '/^sd[^ab]/'
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I am going to try the changes I made out.